# Copiar una parte del texto de un div

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy tratando de copiar solo una parte del numero, del siguiente ejemplo necesito que al aparetar un boton copie desde el numero 6 en adelante. Entiendo que para eso debo usar [slice](/questions/tagged/slice), pero no logro implementarlo aqui. Aclaro que los numeros indicados son solo un ejemplo, el codigo es para copiar un numero de telefono. No puedo modificar el html, solo puedo usar javascript en este caso

```
<button id="cp_btn">Copiar</button>
<div class="numerotelefono">+55 5 666 66-6666</div>
```

```
document.getElementById("cp_btn").addEventListener("click", copy_password);

function copy_password() {
    var copyText = document.querySelector(".numerotelefono");
    var textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
    textArea.value = copyText.textContent;
    document.body.appendChild(textArea);
    textArea.select();
    document.execCommand("Copy");
    textArea.remove();
};
```

Comment: ¿Tu número siempre tendrá espacios, y una longitud fija? ¿Siempre será del quinto caracter en adelante (omitiendo los espacios)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como no proporcionó la fuente que indica el uso de execCommand(), le informo que esta función está marcada como obsoleta debido a un [**bug**](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1220696).

Y se menciona en la página [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) el uso de la [**API Clipboard**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard).

> Deprecated: This feature is no longer recommended. Though some
> browsers might still support it, it may have already been removed from
> the relevant web standards, may be in the process of being dropped, or
> may only be kept for compatibility purposes. Avoid using it, and
> update existing code if possible; see the compatibility table at the
> bottom of this page to guide your decision. Be aware that this feature
> may cease to work at any time.

Hecho este comentario sobre el detalle de estar marcado como **deprecated**, si desea continuar utilizando execCommand() y copiar solo a partir del número 6 en adelante, utilice `copyText.slice(6)` para copiar a partir del carácter 6.
El uso de `try...catch` es para manejar cualquier situación inesperada que pueda surgir.

Lo que `copyText.slice(6)` hace es tomar desde el primero hasta el sexto y mostrará solo la posición a partir de la sexta hacia adelante.

```
|  +  |  5  |  5  |     |  5  |     |  6  |  6  |  6  |     |  6  |  6  |  -  |  6  |  6  |  6  |  6  |  6  |
|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
|  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6  |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
```

Ahora solo tendrás los números.

```
 |  6  |  6  |  6  |     |  6  |  6  |  -  |  6  |  6  |  6  |  6  |  6  |
 |-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
 |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
```

***Cod 1**

```js
document.getElementById("cp_btn").addEventListener("click", copy_password);

function copy_password() {
    var copyText = document.querySelector(".numerotelefono").innerText;
   
    var numero = copyText.slice(6);


    var textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
    textArea.value = numero;
    document.body.appendChild(textArea);
    textArea.select();
    
    try {
      document.execCommand('copy', false, null);
      document.getElementById("okay").innerHTML = "Copiado"
       
    } catch (err) {
      document.getElementById("okay").innerHTML = "Ops"
    }
    
    document.body.removeChild(textArea);
  }
```

```html
<button id="cp_btn">Copiar</button>
<div class="numerotelefono">+55 5 666 66-6666</div>
<span id="okay"></span>
```

*** Código 2, más recomendado**

```js
document.getElementById("cp_btn").addEventListener("click", copy_password);


function copy_password() {
    var copyText = document.querySelector(".numerotelefono").innerText;
    
    var numero = copyText.slice(6);
  
    
    var textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
    textArea.value = numero;
    document.body.appendChild(textArea);
  
     
    if (navigator.clipboard) {
      navigator.clipboard.writeText(numero)
        .then(function () {
          document.getElementById("okay").innerHTML = "Copiado"
        })
        .catch(function (erro) {
        document.getElementById("okay").innerHTML = erro
           
        });
    }  
  
    
    textArea.remove();
  }
```

```html
<button id="cp_btn">Copiar</button>
    <div class="numerotelefono">+55 5 666 66-6666</div>
<span id="okay"></span>
```

**(** *Esta demostración no fue exitosa porque esta* **API** *del portapapeles fue bloqueada debido a una política de permisos aplicada al documento actual.* **)**

Answer (score 2):

Te dejo un ejemplo sencillo con `Slice` aunque tambien se podria hacer con `Substr`, lo que no mencionas es la longitud de la cadena, siempre sera la misma?, habrá algún formato en especifico?.

```js
//DETECTAMOS EL CLICK DEL BOTON Y SE LLAMA A LA FUNCION COPY_PASSWORD
document.getElementById("cp_btn").addEventListener("click", copy_password);

function copy_password() {
  //OBTENEMOS EL ELEMENTO CON CLASE NUMEROTELEFONO
  var copyText = document.querySelector(".numerotelefono");
  //OBTENEMOS EL TEXTO DEL ELEMENTO
  //CON SLICE LE INDICAMOS LA POSICIÓN "6", TOMA EN CUENTA LOS ESPACIOS EN BLANCO Y SE CUENTA DESDE EL "0"
  var text = copyText.textContent.slice(6);
  //CREAMOS EL ELEMENTO DIV
  var textArea = document.createElement("div");
  //AL NUEVO ELEMENTO LE ASIGNAMOS LA CADENA PROCESADA
  textArea.textContent = text;
  //AL BODY LE AÑADIMOS EL ELEMENTO DIV YA CON LA CADENA PROCESADA 
  document.body.appendChild(textArea);

};
```

```html
<button id="cp_btn">Copiar</button>
<div class="numerotelefono">+55 5 666 66-6666</div>
```

Nota: ten cuidado y lleva el orden especifico al añadir elementos nuevos al DOM, así como para asignarle un `atributo o valor`, esto lleva un orden para evitar errores, dime si te sirvió.